# Is there a comprehensive list of IFR terms with definitions?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, terminology

Is there a comprehensive list of IFR terms with definitions easily available?  I am trying to make some flash cards for study

Comment: If you have a spare 99 cents you can buy my app and save yourself the trouble of making flash cards. I’ve taken all of the glossaries from FAA Books and combined them into an app where you can quiz yourself or look up specific terms and acronyms. One of the categories is Instrument Terms. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/faa-glossaries/id454061073?at=10l9Em

Comment: @JScarry That looks like an answer. Why not turn it into one?

Answer (score 4):

The FAA's [Instrument Flying Handbook](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/media/FAA-H-8083-15B.pdf) would be a good start, in particular the glossary.

Comment: FAA-H-8083-16B  Instrument Procedures Handbook also has an appendix of acronyms and a glossary.